# Why does allocating a single 2D array take longer than a loop allocating multiple 1D arrays of the same total size and shape?

Tags: java, performance

I thought it would be quicker to create directly, but in fact, adding loops takes only half the time. What happened that slowed down so much?

Here is the test code

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public class Test_newArray {
    private static int num = 10000;
    private static int length = 10;

    @Benchmark
    public static int[][] newArray() {
        return new int[num][length];
    }

    @Benchmark
    public static int[][] newArray2() {
        int[][] temps = new int[num][];
        for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
            temps[i] = new int[length];
        }
        return temps;
    }

}
```

The test results are as follows.

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
Test_newArray.newArray   avgt   25  289.254 ± 4.982  us/op
Test_newArray.newArray2  avgt   25  114.364 ± 1.446  us/op
```

The test environment is as follows

JMH version: 1.21

VM version: JDK 1.8.0_212, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 25.212-b04

Comment: just guessing, maybe because in case of `int[num][length]`, the continuous space of size `num x length` should be allocated while in case of `int[num][]`, the arrays are allocated arbitrarily

Comment: Do you have any data on what happens in your environment when you vary `num` and `length`?

Comment: @mangusta There are no 2d arrays in Java, I believe your guess is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631081/1570854

Comment: @Lesiak so basically, the above two code snippets are semantically identical?

Comment: If you run JMH with `-prof perfasm`, you might gain some helpful insights. E.g. I can see lots of `ObjArrayKlass::multi_allocate` present in the output of the first method, but absent in the second one. My guess: reflection overhead?

Comment: How much warm up is there, because JIT from `newArray()` would make `newArray2()` faster without warm up, since the expensive part is common to both. What figures do you get if you run each benchmark method by itself in completely separate runs?

Comment: I'm not certain but my first thought is: you're paying a time cost to allocate a single contiguous block of memory for `newArray()` that does not exist with the looped allocation approach.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you increase beyond a count of 25? Do the benchmark numbers remain the same if you run only one test (and comment out the other) at a time?

Comment: @Bohemian Doesn't JMH execute each benchmark in isolation (i.e. in its own JVM) and handle warmup for you? By default, I believe 5 forks are used _per benchmark_, where each fork runs 5 warmup iterations and 5 measurement iterations.

Comment: I wonder, does the JVM allocate fully-formed objects for every array, with a full object header and everything?. There's probably an optimization opportunity to optimize multidimensional arrays into 1 dimensional arrays behind the scenes, and produce fully-fleshed array objects only when they're necessary.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In Java there is a separate bytecode instruction for allocating multidimensional arrays - [`multianewarray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.multianewarray).

- `newArray` benchmark uses `multianewarray` bytecode;
- `newArray2` invokes simple `newarray` in the loop.

The problem is that HotSpot JVM **has no fast path**<sup>*</sup> for `multianewarray` bytecode. This instruction is always executed in VM runtime. Therefore, the allocation is not inlined in the compiled code.

The first benchmark has to pay performance penalty of switching between Java and VM Runtime contexts. Also, the common allocation code in the VM runtime (written in C++) is not as optimized as inlined allocation in JIT-compiled code, just because it is *generic*, i.e. not optimized for the particular object type or for the particular call site, it performs additional runtime checks, etc.

Here are the results of profiling both benchmarks with [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/). I used JDK 11.0.4, but for JDK 8 the picture looks similar.

[image: newArray]

[image: newArray2]

In the first case, 99% time is spent inside [`OptoRuntime::multianewarray2_C`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/8ae33203d600/src/hotspot/share/opto/runtime.cpp#l318) - the C++ code in the VM runtime.

In the second case, the most of the graph is green, meaning that the program runs mostly in Java context, actually executing JIT-compiled code optimized specifically for the given benchmark.

**EDIT**

<sup>*</sup> Actually, HotSpot JVM *can* inline `multianewarray`, but only if the total number of allocations does not exceed `-XX:MultiArrayExpandLimit` which defaults to 6.

So, for example, `new int[5][10]` will be allocated inline in the JIT compiled code, while the allocation of `new int[10][5]` will go through the VM runtime.

Comment: Nice answer, especially including a flame graph – I wish they were more common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a good answer to my doubts.

The problem is the entertainment of rest time. It's not really about optimizing the details.

Answer (score 18):

A note in the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.multianewarray) under the `multianewarray` instruction says:

> It may be more efficient to use `newarray` or `anewarray` ([§newarray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.newarray), [§anewarray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.anewarray)) when creating an array of a single dimension.

Further:

`newArray` benchmark uses `multianewarray` bytecode instruction.

`newArray2` benchmark uses `anewarray` bytecode instruction.

And that is what makes a difference. Let's see the statistics obtained using the `perf` Linux profiler.

For the `newArray` benchmark the hottest methods after inlining are:

```
....[Hottest Methods (after inlining)]..............................................................
 22.58%           libjvm.so  MemAllocator::allocate
 14.80%           libjvm.so  ObjArrayAllocator::initialize
 12.92%           libjvm.so  TypeArrayKlass::multi_allocate
 10.98%           libjvm.so  AccessInternal::PostRuntimeDispatch<G1BarrierSet::AccessBarrier<2670710ul, G1BarrierSet>, (AccessInternal::BarrierType)1, 2670710ul>::oop_access_barrier
  7.38%           libjvm.so  ObjArrayKlass::multi_allocate
  6.02%           libjvm.so  MemAllocator::Allocation::notify_allocation_jvmti_sampler
  5.84%          ld-2.27.so  __tls_get_addr
  5.66%           libjvm.so  CollectedHeap::array_allocate
  5.39%           libjvm.so  Klass::check_array_allocation_length
  4.76%        libc-2.27.so  __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms
  0.75%        libc-2.27.so  __memset_avx2_erms
  0.38%           libjvm.so  __tls_get_addr@plt
  0.17%           libjvm.so  memset@plt
  0.10%           libjvm.so  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space
  0.10%   [kernel.kallsyms]  update_blocked_averages
  0.06%   [kernel.kallsyms]  native_write_msr
  0.05%           libjvm.so  G1ParScanThreadState::trim_queue
  0.05%           libjvm.so  Monitor::lock_without_safepoint_check
  0.05%           libjvm.so  G1FreeCollectionSetTask::G1SerialFreeCollectionSetClosure::do_heap_region
  0.05%           libjvm.so  OtherRegionsTable::occupied
  1.92%  <...other 288 warm methods...>

....[Distribution by Source]....
 87.61%           libjvm.so
  5.84%          ld-2.27.so
  5.56%        libc-2.27.so
  0.92%   [kernel.kallsyms]
  0.03%      perf-27943.map
  0.03%              [vdso]
  0.01%  libpthread-2.27.so
................................
100.00%  <totals>
```

And for the `newArray2`:

```
....[Hottest Methods (after inlining)]..............................................................
 93.45%      perf-28023.map  [unknown]
  0.26%           libjvm.so  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space
  0.22%   [kernel.kallsyms]  update_blocked_averages
  0.19%           libjvm.so  OtherRegionsTable::is_empty
  0.17%        libc-2.27.so  __memset_avx2_erms
  0.16%        libc-2.27.so  __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms
  0.14%           libjvm.so  OptoRuntime::new_array_C
  0.12%           libjvm.so  G1ParScanThreadState::trim_queue
  0.11%           libjvm.so  G1FreeCollectionSetTask::G1SerialFreeCollectionSetClosure::do_heap_region
  0.11%           libjvm.so  MemAllocator::allocate_inside_tlab_slow
  0.11%           libjvm.so  ObjArrayAllocator::initialize
  0.10%           libjvm.so  OtherRegionsTable::occupied
  0.10%           libjvm.so  MemAllocator::allocate
  0.10%           libjvm.so  Monitor::lock_without_safepoint_check
  0.10%   [kernel.kallsyms]  rt2800pci_rxdone_tasklet
  0.09%           libjvm.so  G1Allocator::unsafe_max_tlab_alloc
  0.08%           libjvm.so  ThreadLocalAllocBuffer::fill
  0.08%          ld-2.27.so  __tls_get_addr
  0.07%           libjvm.so  G1CollectedHeap::allocate_new_tlab
  0.07%           libjvm.so  TypeArrayKlass::allocate_common
  4.15%  <...other 411 warm methods...>

....[Distribution by Source]....
 93.45%      perf-28023.map
  4.31%           libjvm.so
  1.64%   [kernel.kallsyms]
  0.42%        libc-2.27.so
  0.08%          ld-2.27.so
  0.06%              [vdso]
  0.04%  libpthread-2.27.so
................................
100.00%  <totals>
```

As we can see, for the slower `newArray` most of the time is spent in the jvm code (87.61% total):

```
22.58%  libjvm.so  MemAllocator::allocate
14.80%  libjvm.so  ObjArrayAllocator::initialize
12.92%  libjvm.so  TypeArrayKlass::multi_allocate
 7.38%  libjvm.so  ObjArrayKlass::multi_allocate
   ...
```

While the `newArray2` uses the `OptoRuntime::new_array_C`, spending much less time allocating the memory for arrays. The total time spent in the jvm code is only 4.31%.

Bonus statistics obtained using the `perfnorm` profiler:

```
Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt        Score    Error  Units
newArray                         avgt    4      448.018 ± 80.029  us/op
newArray:CPI                     avgt             0.359            #/op
newArray:L1-dcache-load-misses   avgt         10399.712            #/op
newArray:L1-dcache-loads         avgt       1032985.924            #/op
newArray:L1-dcache-stores        avgt        590756.905            #/op
newArray:cycles                  avgt       1132753.204            #/op
newArray:instructions            avgt       3159465.006            #/op

Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt        Score    Error  Units
newArray2                        avgt    4      125.531 ± 50.749  us/op
newArray2:CPI                    avgt             0.532            #/op
newArray2:L1-dcache-load-misses  avgt         10345.720            #/op
newArray2:L1-dcache-loads        avgt         85185.726            #/op
newArray2:L1-dcache-stores       avgt        103096.223            #/op
newArray2:cycles                 avgt        346651.432            #/op
newArray2:instructions           avgt        652155.439            #/op
```

Note the difference in the number of cycles and instructions.

---

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: it would be nice if you elaborated on these results because I didn't get anything ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for comment. I updated my answer with some additional details. If you still have any specific questions, please don't hesitate to ask.