# 2D arrays: C++ vs Java (row major vs no major)

Tags: c++

The argument for Java 2D arrays being neither row major nor column major is that "[two-dimensional array in Java is actually an array of references to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631033/5651468)".  C++ also follows the "array of arrays" abstraction.  Then why does C++ require row major order?

Comment: С/C++ doesn't have any inherent array order. Row-major vs column-major is determined by the meaning you assign to the first and second index.

Comment: Whoever told you C++ has row major order, ignore them. Permanently. From now on. At best, they're massively oversimplifying. At worst, they don't actually know C++ (C++ is infamous for this; there are a *ton* of people, even university professors, who teach C++ as "Java without a garbage collector" and think they can get away with just knowing Java and faking it from there). Learn C++ from someone who actually knows C++. A good tip is to ask about things like references, ownership, and move semantics. These are features that have no direct equivalent in Java.

Comment: I dont agree with the answer you link. The question asks "how are they stored" and the answer seems to interpret this in a very narrow way as requiring a very specific layout in memory. If you consider row/column major as "along which dimensions are elements in consecutive memory" this distinctions exists also in java

Comment: To point out the oversimplification, in C++ the C-style arrays you're referring to are weird and annoying to work with. A variable of type `int[N][M]` only works if you know the dimensions at *compile-time*. Otherwise, you're stuck with `int**` and doing a *ton* of manual memory management to get it right. I would never do arrays this way. I would always use `std::vector` (probably a flat one, wrapped in a class to manage indexing), or an `std::array` if I really did know the size at compile-time. C-style arrays have no place in C++ in anything more than the most trivial uses.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo the C standard mentions that "_arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest_)" [e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**].  If it applies to C, surely it applies to C++ as well.

Comment: @Sandeepc- *"If it applies to C, surely it applies to C++ as well."* In this specific case yes, there is an equivalence. But in general, that can lead to fallacies. Be careful when drawing conclusions from one language about the other.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the link in the question

> What we may sometimes think of as two-dimensional array in Java is actually an array of references to arrays. It's not stored linearly in memory.

The difference is in C++ arrays *are* stored linearly in memory.

If you represent an *m* by *n* 2D array in linear memory, it has to either be layed out as *n* groups of *m* items or *m* groups of *n* items. In C and C++ an array like `ary[M][N]` will be stored as `M` groups of `N` items. Whether you want to call those groups rows or columns is arbitrary but the point is the language does specify an order whereas Java does not because a 2D array in Java is not stored "flat".